# Signal R Disonnect delayed in Firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I have noticed that in Firefox, the disconnect event from my Signal R hub is delayed. I am fairly sure this is because the disconnect event from the client is not received and instead the server times out. If I debug my disconnect event, the stopCalled parameters is always false.

I have attempted to manually call the stop event from my JavaScript on the beforeunload event, but this doesn't have any effect. I have read that Firefox does not allow synchronous events in the unload event for security reasons so perhaps it is blocking the call?

**CS**

```
public class WebHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled) { }
}
```

**JS**

```
$.connection.webHub.start().done();
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    $.connection.hub.stop();
});
```

If I call the stop method in the Firefox console it triggers the disconnect event instantly.

**Update 1**

With SignalR JS logging turned on it looks like the disconnect is happening client side, it's just not hitting the server.

```
//navigated page, connection ends

SignalR: Stopping connection." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: EventSource calling close()." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: Window unloading, stopping the connection." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17

//next page load begins

SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'webhub'." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5 jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://website.co.uk/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5 jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: EventSource connected." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state." jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000" jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:81:17
```

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint to see that the disconnect is actually being called? Anything relevant in the JS console?

Comment: Yes, I've added log messages to make sure the .stop method is being called in the JS console. I can confirm it does get called, but the debug point I put on the server side disconnected event isn't triggered until a significant delay has passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by removing the beforeunload event binding. I had originally added this as it solved a similar issue in IE. I have now changed this to only run in IE.

So the JS from the question simply becomes:-

```
$.connection.webHub.start().done();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue with FireFox 86. Spend almost 2-3 days but not found any concrete solution. Here is kind of workaround which works for me. I have just ignore $.connection.hub.stop() when my browser is firefox and it works.

```js
$.connection.webHub.start().done();
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") == -1) {
            $.connection.hub.stop();
        }
});
```